# Using an onblur event to send value to javascript function that will add .00 if it doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, html

From what I understand of onblur, it calls an event when you click out of the textbox. I have a text box where users an enter a value the want to pay.

```html
<input id='Line Item' type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="AmountPaying" class="field m w-input" value="" >
```

If they enter a 1.1 and click out of the box, I want it to change the value to 1.10, Or 1 to 1.00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
onblur="this.value=parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);"
```

```html
<input placeholder="Amount" onblur="this.value=parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);" >
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your script file**

```
document.querySelector('input[name="AmountPaying"]').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.value = parseFloat( this.value ).toFixed( 2 );
});
```