# OnBlur that adds ".00" on the end of the text typed in the textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have textboxes that only inputs numbers and dot for the decimal. My Concern is I want to be able to click from the whitespaces on my page and using onBlur it will fill the last typed number with .00 basically speaking, I want to able to input currency/money figures only. Thank you for those who will answer as of the moment I am using this but it has a bug.

```
  var val = $( this ).val(),
      arr = val.split( '.' );

  if ( arr.length > 1 )
    $( this ).val( arr[ 0 ] + val.substr( val.length - 1 ) + '.00' )
  else
    $( this ).val( val + '.00' )
} ).on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
  return e.charCode == 46 || ( e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57 )
} )
```

Thank you hope anyone can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Post a little more test code and tag it as javascript instead of C# and you'll probably get more help.

Comment: @Nikki9696 thank you. I no other test code but this javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I actually have found the answer to my own question.

this example is onBlur. Refer to this link for the answers.

[Using an onblur event to send value to javascript function that will add .00 if it doesnt exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754210/using-an-onblur-event-to-send-value-to-javascript-function-that-will-add-00-if)